# Why the linker does not remove unused symbols when linking a static library before shared?

Tags: c++, linker

I've got a static library, a dynamic library (which uses the static), and an executable (that uses both):

```
$ cat static.cpp
int use_static()
{
    return {};
}

void unused_in_static() {}
```

```
$ cat shared.cpp
void use_static();

void use_shared()
{
    use_static();
}

void unused_in_shared() {}
```

```
$ cat app.cpp
void use_shared();
void use_static();

int main()
{
    use_shared();
    use_static();
}
```

Then I build them:

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
COMPILE_OPTIONS="-ffunction-sections -fPIC"

g++ $COMPILE_OPTIONS -c -o static.o static.cpp
ar qc libstatic.a static.o

g++ $COMPILE_OPTIONS -c -o shared.o shared.cpp
g++ -Wl,-gc-sections -shared -o libshared.so shared.o libstatic.a

g++ $COMPILE_OPTIONS -c -o app.o app.cpp
g++ -Wl,-gc-sections -Wl,-rpath=. -o app app.o libstatic.a libshared.so
```

The strange thing is, that the compiled `app` contains the function `unused_in_static` which is not used anywhere:

```
readelf -s app | grep unused
    13: 000000000000079a     7 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 _Z16unused_in_staticv
    57: 000000000000079a     7 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 _Z16unused_in_staticv
```

I would expect that it will be removed (thanks to `-ffunction-sections` and `-Wl,-gc-sections`).

The same happens if I add the `libstatic` to the linker after `libshared`:

```
g++ -Wl,-gc-sections -Wl,-rpath=. -o app app.o libstatic.a libshared.so libstatic.a
```

But, surprisingly, if I reverse the order of `libshared` and `libstatic`, everything works ok:

```
g++ -Wl,-gc-sections -Wl,-rpath=. -o app app.o libshared.so libstatic.a
readelf -s app | grep unused
```

Why garbage collecting of the unused function depends on link order? Isn't the first or the second linking order correct?

Comment: Please explain why do you need to remove unused code in practice, and how much weeks of efforts can you spend on that.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch In practice, there are hundreds of unused symbols in my case. It influences the size of the binary that will be uploaded via a slow link so the size matters. It's not worth spending weeks but a few days - it could be.

Comment: Then compressing the binary could be a better option

Comment: Of course, it will be compressed. Still, removing unused functions allows further reduction of the package size.

Comment: How large is your total code base: ten thousands lines of C++ code, or a million lines?

Comment: Did you try with `COMPILE_OPTIONS="-ffunction-sections -fPIC -Os"` ?

Comment: I tried, it didn't help.

Answer (score -2):

> Why the linker does not remove unused symbols when linking a static library before shared?

Because most linkers (e.g. [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) on Linux) are managing entire [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file), not individual functions.

If you use a recent GCC (e.g. [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) in august 2021) and accept to spend a lot more computer time to build your software you might compile and link your application using `g++ -flto -O2` (to enable link time optimizations) both when compiling C++ code and when linking your object files.

In that case ([link time optimization](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/lto/lto.pdf)), the "object files" also contain some [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) representation of your code, and build time (and object file size) is approximately doubled.

> I've got a static library, a dynamic library (which uses the static), and an executable (that uses both)

You better have (on Linux) your static library contain [position -independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code). So compile each member of that library [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `-fPIC`

On Linux, you could load at runtime *some* shared libraries with [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html). In practice, you can load many thousands of them, and you could generate some shared library at runtime (e.g. using [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/)).

Read more about the [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) format. You could use not only [readelf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html) but also [objdump(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html) and [nm(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html) to inspect object files, shared libraries, and [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executables.

In principle you could [extend GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) and [binutils](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/9.1-systemd/chapter06/binutils.html) with your own [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) (for GCC, read its [runtime library license exception](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gcc-exception-3.1.en.html)). In practice, you may need months of work to do so (and the performance win might be a few percents only). The [HorizonEurope](https://ec.europa.eu/info/research-and-innovation/funding/funding-opportunities/funding-programmes-and-open-calls/horizon-europe_en) framework might provide *partial* funding (and you might then contact me by email to `basile@starynkevitch.net` and `basile.starynkevitch@cea.fr` if interested to be part of such a project, where I might use [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/)). But there is [*No silver bullet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet)

A possibility (it takes *lots of work*) might be to develop a GCC plugin which compile every C++ function into a different object file (or member of a static library). So that plugin would split a single C++ translation unit in many smaller ones.

### You could also (in theory) write your own C++ compiler and your own linker.

Consider using [asmjit](https://asmjit.com/) and read Levine's book [*Linkers and loaders*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558604960) and the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) and the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/).

Since all of [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/), [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and [LLVM](https://llvm.org/) are opensource software, you could improve each of them for your needs.

NB. In most cases, writing a GCC plugin, or your own compiler, or your own linker is not worth the efforts. In a few cases, you could spend a year of work doing so. Be sure to ask your manager/client/teacher if it is worth that much efforts (for a performance gain of a few percents). Consider getting the permission to make that an open source project. Perhaps start a PhD on that topic....

Comment: Could you elaborate on "You better have .... `-fPIC`" or put an explanation link for it? I know what it does, but I don't know what's the gotcha while not compiling with that flag?

Comment: In practice, I cannot (without being paid for that). You could read Levine's book [*Linkers and loaders*](https://www.amazon.com/Linkers-Kaufmann-Software-Engineering-Programming/dp/1558604960). Budget a full week of work to read it.

Comment: The question was not why `GCC` doesn't remove unused symbols at all. It does if the options `-ffunction-sections` and `-Wl,-gc-sections` are used (strictly speaking, it removes unused sections). The strange thing is, that it depends on the order of linking.

Comment: I tend to believe that it is Binutils, not GCC, which remove unused symbols.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ture, it's the linker.

Comment: In principle, you can write your own linker. Budget a year of work. Ask your client or manager if it is worth the effort.

Comment: "Because most linkers (e.g. GNU binutils on Linux) are managing entire object files, not individual functions." -- this is not true, and this answer is wrong. Linkers don't care about object files, they care about _sections_. And `-ffunction-sections` is _equivalent_ to splitting the object file into two -- one for each function.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't get why are you still talking about writing/modifying the compiler/linker. This question is completely not about this. It shows a strange (to me) behavior of the linker since in one case it removes the symbols (as expected) and in the other, it doesn't. Probably, there is a reason for that and that's what I'm asking about.

Comment: If the behavior of the linker is strange, and if the linker you are using is open source, you could consider improving that linker. It is up to you to evaluate if that improvement is worth the effort (I believe naively that it is not worth the effort). And you can always study the source code of your linker to understand its behavior.